# Removing class when user navigates to new page in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to remove an animation class from a logo that is an inline SVG whenever a user navigates to a new page on a site ([erdie.com](http://www.erdie.com/)). It's not a huge issue, but it's a little resources intensive when the animation occurs before each page load whenever the user clicks on a new page. The logo is at the top left of the website as you can see and the logo code itself is too long to paste here, but I will paste the header view of what it's printing out. I'm using ASP.Net MVC as my backend with Razor syntax.

**Header.cshtml**

```
<div id="logo-search">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="logo-container seven columns">
            <a id="logo" href="/">
                @Html.Partial("SVGs/_Logo")
            </a>
        </div>
        ...
    </div><!--/ .container -->
</div><!--/ #logo-search -->
```

Obviously, that partial is rendering the inline svg logo as you can see. Basically, I want to create an if/else statement so that if the current URL DOESN'T match the initial URL the user navigated to when FIRST viewing the website, remove the following classes from the inline SVG: `erdie-text`, `industries-text`, `leaf blip`. How might I do this? It's also worth mentioning that if this is possible in JavaScript, I'm open to doing it from that approach.

Comment: Are you facing issue for resource load for multiple time ?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding state to user requests. The best approach is to add a flag in a view model.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.IsFirstLoad = false; // This needs to come from a persistent state
    return View(vm);
}

@if (Model.IsFirstLoad)
{
    @Html.Partial("SVGs/_Logo")
}
```

The tricky part is to figure out how to persist the state.